# Is there a provision to extract the caption for the given picture

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision-api

I am trying to use Vision API to extract the caption for an image

Looks like the Vision API does not provide the caption about the image. It provides the list of objects in the Image.

Looks like [IBM Caption Generator](http://%20https://developer.ibm.com/exchanges/models/all/max-image-caption-generator/) provides the Caption for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today there is no captioning option in Google Cloud Vision API

Request is taken into consideration by google team to (may) develop this as a feature

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137657722